# PHP - If database record is a specific value, only show these buttons

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a multi-step form that allows the user to save for later or submit. If they save for later, i want them to have an option to edit or delete but if they submit, i dont want them to have any option to edit or delete. Although the following code makes sense, its not working; i'm not getting any buttons and it breaks the jquery table plugin and i dont have the search or pagination option:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablesorter table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Date/Time</td>
        <td>Tag</td>
        <td>Serial Number</td>
        <td>Equipment</td>
        <td>Company</td>
        <td>Grand Total</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {        
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$res['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td><span class='label ".$res['labelwarning']."'>".$res['status']."</span></td>";
    echo "<td>".$res['todaysdatetime']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$res['tag']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$res['serialnumber']."</td>";   
    echo "<td>".$res['currentequipment']."</td>";  
    echo "<td>".$res['company']."</td>";  

    echo "<td>".$res['total_grandtotal']."</td>";  



$Submitted = "Submitted";
$Saved = "Saved";

if ($res['labelwarning'] == $Submitted) {
echo "<td></td>";

} elseif ($res['labelwarning'] == $Saved) {
echo "<td><a href=\"invoices_edit.php?id=$res[id]\" class='btn btn-info fa fa-pencil-square'></a> | <a href=\"invoices_delete.php?id=$res[id]\" class='btn btn-danger fa fa-trash' onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\"></a></td>"; 
}


    echo "</tr>";


}
?>


<Script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myTable").dataTable({


"aaSorting": [ [0,'desc'] ]
});
});

</Script>
```

Comment: If you put conditionals be sure that the amount of returned rows will match the amount of columns you have defined in the `<thead>` if they, for some reason,  are not equal the plugin will brake your table.

Comment: It matches though

Comment: I also suppose that you have added the link to the datatable.css and dataTable.js properly in your `html`

Comment: of course, if i remove the if statement, the table works fine.

Comment: But this is what I was asking in the first place. The result of this statement is probably not what you are expecting. A better way to do all this is to have a separate `php` file where you can do your query and store the `html` result in a variable. Using an `ajax` call you can retrieve this result as a response and finally add it to your body.

Comment: ah, i'm not good with ajax. Can you give an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your if/else part to this:

```
    if ($res['labelwarning'] == $Submitted) {
        echo "<td></td>";
    } else{
        echo "<td><a href='invoices_edit.php?id=$res[id]' class='btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></a> | <a href='invoices_delete.php?id=$res[id]' class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash' onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\"></a></td>";
    }
```

Comment: Ah, i made a silly mistake (home simpson DOH!) - Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Oke I will try to explain this process here:

1 - First you will create a `php` file where you will fetch the results you need.

when you are fetching the records you will put your results in a variable like so:

```
$result_html = '';

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {   
    $result_html .= "<tr>";
    $result_html .= "<td>".$res['id']."</td>";
    ...en so on
    $result_html .= "</tr>";
}
```

To return the response to your `ajax` call you need to add also this:

```
echo json_encode($result_html);
```

2 - Before the end `</body>` tag

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/the_php_file',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data : { //only needed if you have to pass parameters to your query  },
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            //data is your html response
            // and #returnedResponse is the id given to your body tag
           $('#returnedResponse').html(data);
           $("#myTable").dataTable();
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });

    });
    </script>
```

3 - Your table

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablesorter table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Date/Time</td>
        <td>Tag</td>
        <td>Serial Number</td>
        <td>Equipment</td>
        <td>Company</td>
        <td>Grand Total</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="returnedResponse">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**NOTE:**
You need to have the link to the jquery.js before your `ajax` call.

This is not a copy and paste solution. You asked for an example on how to do it and here you have a good start point to learn it.

Comment: Never mind, it is never wast of time. Someone else could need it.